# Automatically show centered loading image on Kendo Web ListView, as the Grid does?

Tags: image, listview, spinner, loading

Is there any setting for the Kendo ListView (Web / MVC) that would show the same loading image / spinner that the Kendo Grid does by default?  Hacks accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading image (spinner) has been added to the Kendo ListView. Those who still don't see it, try the *debugger* on RequestEnd event and you will notice.

I know this is an old question but since you reached here this will stop further search and save your time. :-)